# SQL SCD2 weekly statistic grouped by shipping date

Tags: sql, t-sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, scd

I've been having one of those weeks...

I am creating a simple POC for the Director, who is looking for weekly stats of order values shipping.

The scenario they asked is "At the end of each week (Sunday), I want to see the orders total ($), for the next 52 Weeks, based on the shipping date".

Standard SCD2 schemas, expanded below. Simple Date Dimension.

This is simple to answer in its basic form, DIMDATE.DATEKEY_SK = ORDERS.ORDERDATE_SK WHERE ORDERS.CURRENTRECORD ='Y' GROUP BY DIMDATE.WEEKEND. Which gives me all required DIMDATE attributes e.g. WeekStart, WeekEnd, MonthStart, MonthEnd etc etc.

However, the Director has now said he would like to see the previous 12 weeks as well, (-12/+52) in order to compare week on week trends.

Now i could insert all data from the "simple" query into a snapshot table each week which would solve the problem BUT i feel this is the cheats way out and there must be a way to do the same through T-SQL. This is where i am stuck because i have [EffectiveDate] and [EndDate] in my ORDERS table, along with the [OrderShipDate_SK].

Example Schemas Below:

DIMDATE

| DATEKEY_SK | WeekStart | WeekEnd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101 | 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/07 |
| 20250131 | 2023/01/29 | 2023/02/04 |

ORDERS

| ORDERKEY_SK | EffectiveDate | EndDate | OrderId | OrderAmount | OrderShipDate_SK | CurrentRecord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/03 | IF76876 | 35000 | 20230107 | N |
| 1234 | 2023/01/04 | 2023/01/08 | IF76876 | 37000 | 20230107 | N |
| 3345 | 2023/01/09 | 2999/12/31 | IF76876 | 40000 | 20230114 | Y |
| 1432 | 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/12 | IF89996 | 10000 | 20230107 | N |
| 5456 | 2023/01/13 | 2999/12/31 | IF89996 | 12000 | 20230114 | Y |
| 1932 | 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/22 | IF62336 | 10000 | 20230131 | N |
| 7456 | 2023/01/23 | 2999/12/31 | IF62336 | 12000 | 20230218 | Y |

What I'm after is like the below:

| WeekStart | WeekEnd | OrderTotal | ShippingWeekEnd (OrderShipDate) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/07 | 47000 | 2023/01/07 |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/07 | 0 | 2023/01/14 |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/07 | 0 | 2023/01/21 |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/07 | 0 | 2023/01/28 |
| 2023/01/01 | 2023/01/07 | 10000 | 2023/02/04 |
| 2023/01/08 | 2023/01/14 | 52000 | 2023/01/14 |
| 2023/01/08 | 2023/01/14 | 0 | 2023/01/21 |
| 2023/01/08 | 2023/01/14 | 0 | 2023/01/28 |
| 2023/01/08 | 2023/01/14 | 10000 | 2023/02/04 |
| 2023/01/15 | 2023/01/21 | 0 | 2023/01/21 |
| 2023/01/15 | 2023/01/21 | 0 | 2023/01/28 |
| 2023/01/15 | 2023/01/21 | 10000 | 2023/02/04 |
| 2023/01/15 | 2023/01/21 | 0 | 2023/02/11 |
| 2023/01/22 | 2023/01/28 | 12000 | 2023/01/28 |
| 2023/01/22 | 2023/01/28 | 0 | 2023/02/04 |
| 2023/01/22 | 2023/01/28 | 0 | 2023/02/11 |
| 2023/01/22 | 2023/01/28 | 12000 | 2023/02/18 |

I want to show (64) rows for each week start/end with the sum of orders, grouped by the shipping week end (always Saturdays) E.g. If the order changes mid week only the latest record during that week is factored in at the end of the week.

I just cant figure out how i need to construct the query to do this. Existing Query Below

```
SELECT SUM(OrderTotal),DIMDATE.WeekEnd
FROM ORDERS
LEFT JOIN DIMDATE ON DIMDATE.DATEKEY_SK = ORDERS.OrderShipDate_SK
WHERE ORDERS.CurrentRecord = 'Y'
GROUP BY DIMDATE.WeekEnd DESC
```

Comment: Hi - it’s unclear, to me, what you are trying to achieve. Can’t you just take the current record for each order and group by the Ship Date? What are these 24 rows for each week? It’s not obvious how the sample data you’ve provided equates to the result table you’ve given: how do you get 47000 for 2023/01/07?

Comment: Hi - 24 rows for each week was a typo. I need to show 64 rows. For example, this week starts on 2023/01/22. Therefore i would need 64 rows dated 2023/01/22, showing the last 12 weeks order totals and the next 52 weeks order totals. The 47000 is because the order ID IF76876 was amended on 2023/01/04 to 37000 and would have been the current record for that week. Add to this order IF89996 for 10000. Both orders were due to be shipped on 2023/01/07. Basically, i cant group as suggested because the current record may not have existed on that particular week when looking back at history (12 weeks).

Comment: Hi - so do you just want to include the version of an order record that was effective on the Order Ship Date? If so then you just need a WHERE clause that does something like (pseudo-code): EffectiveDate <= to_date(OrderShip_Date_SK) AND  EndDate >= to_date(OrderShip_Date_SK)

Answer (score 1):

I think i have cracked it after sleeping on it.

First use the date dimensions to list all possible week start combinations, then do some extra calculations to generate some other dates.

```
WITH
DATES AS (
SELECT distinct
DDATE.FirstOfWeek as 'WeekStart',
CAST(REPLACE(DDATE.FirstOfWeek,'-','')as int) AS 'skWeekstart', -- Want this as int for joins
DDATE.LastOfWeek,
CAST(REPLACE(DDATE.LastOfWeek,'-','')as int) AS 'skWeekend', -- Want this as int for joins
CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, FirstOfWeek)-1, 0) as date) AS LastMonth,
CAST(REPLACE(CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, FirstOfWeek), 0) as date),'-','') as int) AS MonthStart,
CAST(REPLACE(EOMONTH(FirstOfWeek),'-','') as int) as MonthEnd
FROM vw_dim_date DDATE
WHERE EOMONTH(FirstOfWeek) > '2021-01-01' AND LastOfWeek <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7)  --- No point looking into the future as it hasnt happened yet.
),
```

| WeekStart | skWeekstart | LastOfWeek | skWeekend | LastMonth | MonthStart | MonthEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-03 | 20210103 | 2021-01-09 | 20210109 | 2020-12-01 | 20210101 | 20210131 |
| 2021-01-10 | 20210110 | 2021-01-16 | 20210116 | 2020-12-01 | 20210101 | 20210131 |
| 2021-01-17 | 20210117 | 2021-01-23 | 20210123 | 2020-12-01 | 20210101 | 20210131 |
| 2021-01-24 | 20210124 | 2021-01-30 | 20210130 | 2020-12-01 | 20210101 | 20210131 |
| 2021-01-31 | 20210131 | 2021-02-06 | 20210206 | 2020-12-01 | 20210101 | 20210131 |

Now get all the surrogate keys for the ORDERS and the effective dates of those records.

```
--- Get all the surrogate keys for ORDERS and the effective dates. Only looking for non deleted records and those with a shipping date 
ORDERS AS (
SELECT 
skOrder,orderid,
CAST(REPLACE(EffectiveDate,'-','') as int) as skeffdate,
CAST(REPLACE(EndDate,'-','') as int) as skenddate
FROM vw_dim_Orders
WHERE IsDeleted =0 AND skShippingDate <>-1
),
```

| skOrder | OrderId | skeffdate | skenddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12005892 | IG67787 | 20220325 | 20220710 |
| 12017996 | IG577872 | 20220711 | 99991231 |
| 12000030 | IH66798 | 20211110 | 20220324 |

Join back to the DATES CTE and group by Date attributes. Join is using skeffectivedate < skweekend which works because im selecting the latest surrogate key for that record for that week.

```
--- Now join back into the weeks to get a list of ORDERS for each week.
--- 1) Join on ORDER effective date < dates current weekend
--- 2) Get the MAX surrogate Key for that ORDER for that week. This ensures the latest record for that week is taken. E.g. 2 + changes, only the last change for that week is taken.
ORDERSKS AS (
SELECT DATES.*,
MAX(skOrders) AS skOrders
FROM DATES
LEFT JOIN ORDERS ON (skeffdate < skWeekend)
GROUP BY DATES.WeekStart,DATES.skWeekstart,DATES.LastOfWeek,DATES.LastMonth,DATES.MonthStart,DATES.MonthEnd,skWeekend,orderId
)
```

This provides a list of ORDER surrogate keys which were valid on that week. Natuarlly there are millions of rows returned, but the results are narrow so it runs in seconds.

| WeekStart | skWeekstart | LastOfWeek | skWeekend | LastMonth | MonthStart | MonthEnd | skOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-22 | 20230122 | 2023-01-28 | 20230128 | 2022-12-01 | 20230101 | 20230131 | 12011381 |
| 2023-01-22 | 20230122 | 2023-01-28 | 20230128 | 2022-12-01 | 20230101 | 20230131 | 12028584 |
| 2023-01-22 | 20230122 | 2023-01-28 | 20230128 | 2022-12-01 | 20230101 | 20230131 | 12014886 |
| 2023-01-22 | 20230122 | 2023-01-28 | 20230128 | 2022-12-01 | 20230101 | 20230131 | 12011382 |

With this i can join back to the dimension on the SK to get the shipping dates and order totals and tally from there.

It may not be the prettiest but it gives me every single order record for each week, factoring in if the record was updated mid week. This is really only for history to be able to look back 12 weeks, but i can look back as far as i have data now.